# Is there any way to get the xpath of a selenium web element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have a database filled with keywords and I have to get the xpaths of the web elements containing these words. (there is an expandable list button next to every word. to click on that I need to get the xpath of the keyword and modify it to get the button XPath).

I can get the selenium web element using,

```
keyword_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{keyword}')]")
```

this only gets the selenium web element for the element containing the keyword like this,

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1df8dbbae8c93fd772a5134ed0666a7a", element="b3d2bc8d-0c8c-4fb0-b3d1-2a5d49537567")>
```

and the HTML dev element looks like this.

```
<span class="fancytree-node actlitetreeitem fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
    <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
    <span class="fancytree-checkbox"></span>
    <span class="fancytree-title">SNAPCHAT</span>
</span>
```

'SNAPCHAT' is the keyword and I need access to the 'fancytree-checkbox' element. but I have to get it using the keyword SNAPCHAT.

Is there any way to get the xpath of the web element out of this?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML for keyword element along with button element with parent node as well?

Comment: @KunduK it's been edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the `xpath` to identify the element `fancytree-checkbox`.

Use `preceding-sibling`

```
keyword_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{keyword}')]/preceding-sibling::span[1]")
```

OR Identify the **parent** node and then its **child**

```
 keyword_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[.//*[contains(text(), '{keyword}')]]//span[@class='fancytree-checkbox']")
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I also kinda found a way to access that element by directing backwards using the keyword_element element. but your method works better.